# How to send emojis with text using jQuery Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have a reqirement that user can enter the Emjois and text together. I would like to pass this text with emoji to server(via Ajax post call) and save in the database(sql server). We are using the same application for native mobile(andriod, iOS) apps as wel so it should handle the native apps emojies as well.

Can you please assist on this and give your suggestions please?

```
User entered as: **Hello this is sample text ? ! @ # $ ✌‍**
```

Current code:

```
var memo = $('#txtMemo').val();
var recipientFName = $('#recipientFirstName').val();

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Mobile//Send",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            'recipientFirstName': recipientFName,
            'memo': memo ,
        },
        success: function (response) {
        },
        error: function () {
        }
    });
```

Comment: I don't see how emojis are a problem, if youi're storing text in utf-8 encoding.

Comment: could you please provide sample code.. above is my current code that I am sending via Ajax call.

Comment: Be sure to use something like split(",") on a list of emojis, so js doesn't rip apart your emojis. Example: `var emojis = ",,,,".split(",");`

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. i've created some jQuery document (dom) related tests below...

- `.on('click', '[name="html"]'` get this button dom html
- `.on('click', '[name="data"]'` get this button `[data-emojis]` value
- `.on('click', '[name="variable"]'` use js `let result` variable value
- `.on('click', '[name="json"]'` run jQuery json ajax and get response
- `.on('submit', 'FORM'` get input `[name="emojis"]` value

The tests above return result/response too `$result` div as html, and also `console.log()` result.

I cant seem to find an issue in these tests. See tests code below...

```js
// constant result div for button on click results
const $result = $('#result');

// button name html on click function
$(document).on('click', '[name="html"]', function() {

  // get emojis html from button child span
  let result = $(this).find('SPAN').html();

  // log result
  console.clear();
  console.log(result);

  // render result html
  $result.html(result);

});

// button name data on click function
$(document).on('click', '[name="data"]', function() {

  // get emojis from button data attribute emojis
  let result = $(this).data('emojis');

  // log result
  console.clear();
  console.log(result);

  // render result html
  $result.html(result);

});

// button name variable on click function
$(document).on('click', '[name="variable"]', function() {

  // js variable with emojis
  let result = '✌';

  // log result
  console.clear();
  console.log(result);

  // render result html
  $result.html(result);

});

// button name json on click function
$(document).on('click', '[name="json"]', function() {

  // jquery ajax call
  $.ajax({

    // get json file with emojis 
    url: 'https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5fb3211d5be6ec73e94f6285',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',

    // on success response function
    success: function(response) {

      // json response with emojis
      let result = response[0].emojis;

      // log result
      console.clear();
      console.log(result);

      // render result html
      $result.html(result);


    },

    // on fail response function
    error: function() {

      // console err
      console.log("json emoji error");

    },


  });


});

// form test on submit function
$(document).on('submit', 'FORM', function(e) {

  // prevent form submit default
  e.preventDefault();

  // this form input with name emojis
  let result = $('[name="emojis"]',this).val();

  // log result
  console.clear();
  console.log(result);

  // render result html
  $result.html(result);

});
```

```css
BUTTON {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

FORM {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

INPUT {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 28px;
}

#result {
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 4rem;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: fixed;
  width: calc(50% - 30px);
}

.row {
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-right: -10px;
}

.col {
  width: 50%;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  float: left;
}

BODY {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 1000px;
}

*, ::after, ::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">

    <button name="html">
      Click for html result <span>✌</span> 
    </button>

    <button name="data" data-emojis="✌">
      Click for data-emoji result ✌
    </button>
    
    <button name="variable">
      Click js var value result ✌
    </button>

    <button name="json">
      Click json ajax response ✌➕❤️
    </button>
    
    <form>
      <input type="text" name="emojis" value="" />
      <button>
        Submit emojis form above 
      </button>
    </form>  

  </div>
  <div class="col">
  
    <div id="result"></div>
    
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here is a remote json file with emojis that i'm using in last on click test.. https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5fb3211d5be6ec73e94f6285

I'm on a mac, so not sure how these results return on other operating system browsers. These jQuery browser tests above return OK for me in chrome

Here is a fiddle too of the above tests... https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/dLao23yq/

Comment: Thank you joshmoto for the help. Your answers are helpful but main challange is, need to pass the Emojis via Ajax call and I see you are submitting the whole form at a time. Could you please sugguest if we can pass the emojies via Jquery Ajax? Also, I don't see any proper solution found anywhere. It would be very helpful if you can assist on this... ❤️❤️

Comment: No worries. But i'm not technically submitting the whole form, it's an example jquery `.on('submit')` function which upon submitting gets this form child input `name="emojis"` using `.val()`, just like your code, and returns it using `.html()` to the `$result` div. Could you possibly add a little bit more context (html) of how you are grabbing the values? You are specifying a `dataType: "json"` and `url "/Mobile//Send"`, but how is your passed data handled behind the scenes?

Comment: On your ajax `success`, what does the console logging the `response` data var? Would be handy to post the response.

Comment: Sure, our current implementation is send plain text and couple of special sybols to DB. Fo this we are sending all information via JSON format using JQuery Ajax. 
Now the new requirement is to allow emojis along with text and some special characters. Emojis should be supported either from Desktop/Andriod Keyborad/iOS keyborad emojis. 
We need to save this content in SQL server DB and need send the same emoji with text info content to users so that they can see the same content with emojis.